# How to stop static file being cached when called from iPhone 6 in Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, caching

I'm writing a live chat message / chat system in Xcode 7.2.1. My system works on iPhone simulator (iPhone 6). But when I run on a real iPhone 6, both wireless and 4G the response of the chat is slower. I expect the real iPhone caches files it gets from a server. My estimate is this cache is about 20 seconds, which is of course too slow for a live chat.

The server side uses MySQL to store incoming messages. When a new message comes in, a PHP script writes a static JSON file. This is done to avoid MySQL calls every few seconds to see if the messages are new.

The file on the server has a bespoke name, xxxxxx.chat. Where, xxxxx is something to identify which users are talking.

If my assumption is correct, that the real device is caching requests is there a away to reduce the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a dummy variable to the URL query which forces a new copy each time, for example:

```
let theUrl    = "http://domain.com/\(filename)?cache=\(now())"

func now() -> Int
{
   return Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
}
```

Adding a time stamp to the query forces a fresh download every second.